# How should I setup this "drawer" view app?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am using a framework `MMDrawerController` which has been awesome.  I am just trying to structure my code well.  I have just the left side nav.  And I have it setup like this right now:

```
UIViewController *leftSideDrawerViewController = [[MenuNavigationViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

// ****************************** just my initial login viewcontroller
UIViewController *centerViewController = [[***LoginViewController*** alloc] init];// The Question I have is right here
// ******************************

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:centerViewController];

self.drawerController = [[MMDrawerController alloc]
                         initWithCenterViewController:navigationController
                         leftDrawerViewController:leftSideDrawerViewController
                         rightDrawerViewController:nil];
self.window setRootViewController:self.drawerController];
```

Should basically I just make my left view controller my `MenuViewController` which will never be changed.  And then I make my center view controller my `LoginViewController` and this view will obviously need to be changed eventually.  I have about 5 view controllers available to be selected in the left nav, then from those viewcontrollers accessed from the left nav, I will push viewcontrollers.  How can I set this up?  It seems to me like I would need multiple navigation controllers.  One for each viewcontroller available in the left side nav.

How can I setup multiple navigation controllers and how can I transition between those navigation controllers on the center view?

Thanks for the help, just trying to setup this app well!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your requirement is something like this take a look at the below demo code that i've created hope it helps you :)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7exzdzqnm6i05wd/DeckViewDemo%202.zip